# Checking file existence in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there a simple way in Julia to check whether a file in the current working directory exists (something like `test = os.path.isfile("foo.txt")` in Python or `inquire(file = "foo.txt", exist = test)` in Fortran)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Julia has the `isfile()` function to test for a regular file:

```
julia> isfile("foo.txt")
false

shell> touch foo.txt

julia> isfile("foo.txt")
true
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.isfile):

> Returns true if *path* (the parameter) is a regular file, false otherwise.

Comment: So simple and convenient!